# How can students self-learn creativity in math that "demand more than just deduction"?

Tags: self-learning

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason  (1st edn 2008)*](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 112.

> You might suppose that logic does at least underlie the mental abilities of
>   mathematicians and logicians. Some of them have thought so too, but the
>   disciplines demand more than just deduction. The Indian genius Srinivasa
>   Ramanujan, who died in 1920, left behind a body of work that continues to
>   occupy mathematicians, but proof was not crucial to his many conjectures. As
>   another great mathematician, G.H. Hardy wrote about him, “[he] combined
>   a power of generalization, a feeling for form, and a capacity for rapid modification of his hypotheses, that were often really startling, and made him, in his
>   own peculiar field, without a rival in his day.

Is this  psychologist correct that mathematical discoveries demand more than deduction? If yes:

1. What's the term for this creativity?
2. How can undergraduate students learn it?

Comment: There are already questions on this site about creativity; try using the search feature. Your previous post on MESE also included an excerpt about deductive reasoning from this same book [and the same author, for whom listing the degree of "BA" strikes me as odd...] and was closed; I am not sure that this site is ideal for the questions you are asking. That said, maybe Tall's [The psychology of advanced mathematical thinking](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9669377446194124820&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33) or the cited text of Hadamard [or its inspiration by Poincare...] would be of interest.

Comment: I think this question is about mathematics education, broadly interpreted, and is an acceptable question for this website. The "how can learn" part is a tad broad, though.

Comment: Likely there's no way to learn Ramanujan's level of insight.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, maybe not get to Ramanujan's wizardry, but learn some. Just like Pólya's book on problem solving is a help.

Comment: @TommiBrander I agree that the question is "about mathematics education, broadly interpreted," but it asks (1) whether mathematical discovery involves more than deduction and (2) if so, how undergrads can... "learn it." I believe this is *way* too broad - more than just a "tad"!

Comment: In my experience, as one who has never been particularly gifted mathematically, there is a huge aspect of mental conditioning in this so called creativity. It wasn't until I spent enough time with mathematical structures that my own intuitions began falling in line with mathematical reality. This is when my "creative math" began (and it was fairly late; probably the third year of grad school).

Answer (score 1):

Polya's classic was already mentioned by @vonbrand.
It is full of insights.

> Polya, George. *How to solve it: A new aspect of mathematical method*. No. 246. Princeton university press, 2004.
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

I hesitate to recommend the following as I have not read it, but it is in the
same vein, albeit more algorithmically oriented:

> Michalewicz, Zbigniew, and David B. Fogel. *How to solve it: modern heuristics*. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013. ([Springer link](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540224945).)
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---